# Invoke mirrored global function

Tags: reflection, dart, dart-mirrors

I'm searching all global annotated functions in my lib:

```dart
@MyAnnotation()
String func(arg1, arg2) => "test";

main() {
    var routines = m.currentMirrorSystem().findLibrary(#my.lib).declarations.values
      .where((m.DeclarationMirror dm) =>
        dm is m.MethodMirror && dm.metadata.map((m.InstanceMirror im) => im.reflectee)
            .any((refl) => refl is MyAnnotation)
      );
     // this works all ok
}
```

Now I have `List<DeclarationMirror>` of my annotated functions. But I need to invoke it later. ClosureMirror has `invoke` method, but I cannot see any way to get this for my either MethodMirror or Symbol of routine.
I cannot use just new ClosureMirror(func) as I have dozens of my annotated functions and I don't know every name. Also I dont have any ClassMirror or InstanceMirror.

So question is, how to invoke global mirrored functions by its Symbol or MethodMirror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  m.MethodMirror f = routines[0];
    (f.owner as m.LibraryMirror).invoke(f.simpleName, ['a', 'b']);
```

Comment: Oh, this one works:
    
    class AnnotatedRoutine implements Function {
        final m.MethodMirror routine;
        UpgradeScript(this.routine);
        String call(arg1, arg2) =>
            (routine.owner as m.LibraryMirror).invoke(routine.simpleName, [ arg1, arg2 ]).reflectee;
    }


markdown here sucks

Comment: You don't need `as m.LibraryMirror` if you have different owners, I just added it to get autocompletion.